# Filter date with Java

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I am trying filters with Java, I can't use "Select ..." for find results.

The problem is that my object always join in my array.

My datas are ->

```
Registro 1-> Fecha Inicio "2018-09-01" , Fecha Fin -> "2018-09-30"
Registro 2-> Fecha inicio "2018-10-01" , Fecha Fin -> "2018-10-05"
Registro 3-> Fecha inicio "2017-12-31" , Fecha Fin -> "2018-11-30"
Registro 4-> Fecha inicio "2018-12-01" , Fecha Fin -> "2019-10-01"
Registro 5-> Fecha inicio "2018-12-30" , Fecha Fin -> "2018-12-31"
Registro 6-> Fecha inicio "2018-11-30" , Fecha Fin -> "2018-12-01"
```

The user insert -> `"2018-12-01" hasta el "9999-31-12"` for filter.

Register 4 should be insert to array because my user insert "2018-12-01" and my register have the same Date Start.

Register 5º should be insert to array because my user insert "`2018-12-01" and finish year->9999` THEN how my register is between, It should insert to array.

Register 6º -> shold be insert to array because the date End because its end date corresponds to the period of time between the start date and the end date of the user, that is, the user wants between "2018-12-01" until "9999-31-12" and the date End of registration is "2018-12-01"

```
public List<Article> filterResult(String paramSelect, String dateStart, String dateEnd) {
    List<Article> list = Collections.emptyList();

    try {
        // Sino me ponen fecha de fin, la establezco al máximo.
        if(dateStart != null && dateEnd == null) {
            dateEnd ="9999-31-12";
            list = (List<Article>) this.pgRepository.findAll();
            list =  this.getStart(list, dateStart, dateEnd);
        }
     } catch (Exception e) {
         LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
     }

     return list;
}

private List<Article> getStart(List<Article> list, String dateStart, String dateEnd) throws ParseException {
    DateFomrat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
    Date userDate = df.parse(dateStart);
    Date userEnd = df.parse(dateEnd);

    List<Article> filter = new ArrayList<Article>();

    for(Article param : list) {
        Date paramStart = df.parse(param.getStartdatevalidity());
        Date paramEnd = df.parse(param.getEnddatevalidity());

        if(paramStart.after(userDate) || paramEnd.before(userDate) && paramStart.after(userEnd) ||  paramEnd.before(userEnd)) {
            filter.add(param);
        }
    }

    return filter;
}
```

I have two problems ->
1º My object always is guarded in my array. 2º I don't know if my logic is correct...

Thanks and sorry for my English.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you want this:

```
    if (! (paramEnd.before(userDate) || paramStart.after(userEnd))) {
        filter.add(param);
    }
```

Yes, this simple. You may say that I have reversed the condition. You don’t want the articles whose validity end before `userDate`, and you also don’t want those whose validity begin after `userEnd`. All other articles have an overlap with the user interval, so are included.

That said, the `Date` class that you are using is long outdated and has a number of design problems. And `SimpleDateFormat` is renowned for trouble. Furthermore a `Date` despite its name does not represent a date, but a point in time. I recommend you use `LocalDate` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for representing a date, both inside your `Article` class and in your search and filter code. As an added bonus `LocalDate` parses your date format of `yyyy-MM-dd` without any explicit formatter since this format is standard (it’s also known as ISO 8601). For example:

```
public class Article {

    LocalDate startDateValidity;
    LocalDate endDateValidity;

    // Note that this constructor accepts string arguments for convenience
    public Article(String startValidity, String endValidity) {
        this.startDateValidity = LocalDate.parse(startValidity);
        this.endDateValidity = LocalDate.parse(endValidity);
    }

    // getters etc.

}
```

In `filterResult` parse `dateStart` and `dateEnd` into `LocalDate` in the same say as in the constructor above. If `dateEnd` is missing, set `userEnd` tp `LocalDate.MAX`. Your `if` condition isn’t changed much when all the dates are `LocalDate`; there’s an `is` in front of the method names:

```
    if (! (paramEnd.isBefore(userDate) || paramStart.isAfter(userEnd))) {
        filter.add(param);
    }
```

**EDIT: let’s test it.**

Using the dates of the 6 registrations from your question:

```
    List<Article> list = Arrays.asList(
            new Article("2018-09-01", "2018-09-30"),
            new Article("2018-10-01", "2018-10-05"),
            new Article("2017-12-31", "2018-11-30"),
            new Article("2018-12-01", "2019-10-01"),
            new Article("2018-12-30", "2018-12-31"),
            new Article("2018-11-30", "2018-12-01"));

    LocalDate userDate = LocalDate.parse("2018-12-01");
    LocalDate userEnd = LocalDate.MAX;

    for(Article param : list) {
        LocalDate paramStart = param.getStartDateValidity();
        LocalDate paramEnd = param.getEndDateValidity();

        if (! (paramEnd.isBefore(userDate) || paramStart.isAfter(userEnd))) {
            System.out.println("Included " + param);
        }
    }
```

This snippet printed the following output:

```
Included Article [startDateValidity=2018-12-01, endDateValidity=2019-10-01]
Included Article [startDateValidity=2018-12-30, endDateValidity=2018-12-31]
Included Article [startDateValidity=2018-11-30, endDateValidity=2018-12-01]
```

You will recognize the dates of registrations number 4, 5 and 6, which were the ones that you said you wanted to be inserted into your filter array.

### What went wrong in your code?

> I have two problems -> 1º My object always is guarded in my array. 2º I don't know if my logic is correct...

You are correct that your logic is incorrect. Let’s look at your `if` condition:

```
if(paramStart.after(userDate)
        || paramEnd.before(userDate) && paramStart.after(userEnd)
        || paramEnd.before(userEnd)) …
```

`&&` has higher precedence than `||`, so it is interpreted as though there were brackets around `paramEnd.before(userDate) && paramStart.after(userEnd)`. This middle part of the condition will realistically never be true, though, but an article will be included if either the first or the last part is. Only registrations number 5 fulfils the first part of the condition because `after` means “strictly after”. However all 6 registrations fulfil the last part, `paramEnd.before(userDate) && paramStart.after(userEnd)`. With `||` between the parts this is enough that all 6 articles are included in the filter result.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: if (!(paramEnd.isBefore(LocalDate.parse(dateEnd)) || paramStart.isAfter(LocalDate.parse(dateEnd)))) { ?? Are you sure ? It never join ...

Comment: It still looks right in my own eyes, but I didn’t test it. What do you mean that it never joins? I had assumed that your dates were inclusive since you wanted Registro 6 to be included. See also [Problem calculating overlapping date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7468948/problem-calculating-overlapping-date-ranges) (there are many similar questions).

Comment: Sorry I use translate, I wanted say : " that if is bad ", Never join,

Comment: You sound skeptical? I have added a code snippet that demonstrates how my `if` statement works (and the other suggestions I have given). Doesn’t it produce the output you had wanted?

Comment: Nop, I tried your code, but this code fail ... Sorry for my English.

Comment: If you quote the error message you get, I can probably help. To “but this code fail” I can just say: sorry. As I said, it works on my computer.

Comment: Wait, I don't understand, now yes run .... -.-'' Very thanks I don't understand because the other day this doesn't run and now yes, sorry, sorry .

Comment: but One question , if I put a date finish, this code run ? I see -> LocalDate.MAX; I need filter for date Start from user and date Finish User, AND if my user doesn't put notthing in date End , then I join "9999-12-31"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181213/discussion-between-ole-v-v-and-edubw).

Answer (score 0):

Edit 2 - removed questions asked here for more clarification as got the concept by Ole V.V's answer and I have upvoted it being clear helpful answer.

**My suggestion based on provided details -**

1. Using `boolean java.util.Date.after(Date when)`

   `//Change suggestion in original code
   if(paramStart.after(userDate) || paramEnd.before(userDate) paramEnd.before(userEnd)) {
               filter.add(param);
    }`
2. Using `int java.util.Date.compareTo(java.util.Date anotherDate)`

Answer (score 0):

I offer not to use date parsing from `String` to `Date` at all. In case data is stored and entered by the user in the same format `yyyy-mm-dd`, then to compare two dates it is enough just compare two strings.

*P.S.* Actually, to compare huge list of dates in same format, we use *RadixSort* for string.

In this case, your `getStart()` method becomes very simple:

```
public static List<Article> getStart(List<Article> list, String dateStart, String dateEnd) {
    final Predicate<String> isInRange = date -> date.compareTo(dateStart) >= 0 && date.compareTo(dateEnd) <= 0;
    final Predicate<Article> isIntersect = article -> isInRange.test(article.getStartdatevalidity()) || isInRange.test(article.getEnddatevalidity());
    return list.stream().filter(isIntersect).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```